# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException in Spring Boot integration test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot 2 application where I have a `JdbcPersistenceHelper` like following:

```
@Component
public class JdbcPersistenceHelper {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public JdbcPersistenceHelper(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    // Some persistence-related utility methods here
```

I'm using this class to generate some fixture data from my tests and I have several `@DataJpaTest` annotated tests successfully using it. However, when I try to use it in an integration test (a `@SpringBootTest` annotated test class), it got the following error:

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

My integration test looks like follows:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK, classes = ExchangeRateStoreApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class GenerateStrategyRatesTest {
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    JdbcPersistenceHelper jdbcPersistenceHelper;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        jdbcPersistenceHelper.persistAllUpdatingStrategiesAvailable();
        jdbcPersistenceHelper.persistAllExchangeRateProvidersAvailable();
    }

    // Some test methods here
```

Currently, I'm working against a H2 inmemory DB, and my Spring Boot's `application.yaml` looks like follows:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:ExchangeRateDB;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    username: err
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark you test class or before method to be bound to a transaction:

```
@BeforeEach
@Transactional
void setUp() {
```

or

```
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class GenerateStrategyRatesTest
```

you cannot perform persist / update / delete operations without a running transaction.